# Conditional incrementing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data table like this:

```
user_id  event_time
1        1456812346
1        1456812350
1        1456812446
1        1456812950
1        1456812960
```

Now, I am trying to define a 'session_id' for the user based on the event_time. If the events come after a lag of 180 seconds, the events are considered as from new session. So, I would like an output similar to:

```
user_id  event_time  session_id
1        1456812346   1
1        1456812350   1
1        1456812446   1
1        1456812950   2
1        1456812960   2
```

The session is incremented at 4th row as the time is 504 secs after 3rd row and thus more than the threshold of 180 secs.

In Mysql, I could just declare a variable and then increment it conditionally. As variable creation is not supported in BigQuery, is there an alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user_id, event_time, session_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, event_time, event_time - last_time > 180 AS new_session, 
    SUM(IFNULL(new_session, 1)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_time) AS session_id
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, event_time,
      LAG(event_time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_time) AS last_time
    FROM YourTable
  )
)
ORDER BY event_time
```